# How to get sorted list using criteria and projections

Tags: hibernate, criteria

Here is my code,

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Category.class);     
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("id", 102));
            criteria.setProjection(Projections.projectionList().add(Projections.property("item")).add((Projections.alias(Projections.count("item.itemId"), "itemsCount"))));
    criteria.addOrder(Order.desc("itemsCount"));

    List<items> items = criteria.list();
```

Thanks a lot !

Comment: What are you trying to do? Can you publish the SQL you want to use. I am not sure if you can use **count(itemId)** with out a group by clause.

Comment: I just need all categories order by number of items, itemId is referenced column in categories.

Answer (score 0):

not directly possible with criteria

[using hql](https://stackoverflow.com/a/604664/671619)

[using a formula property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5119084/671619) (probably with a NOOP implementation of ISetter as access if you definitly dont want the property in your class)